# CSS - Proportionally make an image as tall as possible without exceeding a pixel limit, and as wide as possible without exceeding parent's width

Tags: css

I have an image within a wrapper div. I need to restrict the height of the image to no greater than 150px. The width of the image cannot exceed the width of the parent div (the wrapper). If either the width or the height reaches its limit, the other dimension should not increase anymore so as to preserve the original proportions of the image.

I am manipulating the CSS for the image with id #frameImage and the CSS of the wrapper div with id #imageWrapper:

```
#imageWrapper
{
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
}

#frameImage
{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 150px;
}
```

Visually, this seems to work for images that have at least one dimension that exceeds one of these limits. However, I have some images whose true heights are less than 150px and whose true widths are less than the wrapper div. In this case I want to blow up the image to dimensions beyond it's natural ones until its height hits 150px or its width hits the width of the wrapper.

In its current state, these small images as I have described in the paragraph above keep their original size and tuck themselves into the upper left corner of the parent div without expanding to meet one of these limits.

I have been messing around for a few hours with `auto` and `100%` heights and widths without ever getting the result I want.

Is there a simple way to achieve this that I am missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

remove the max preffix, from both declarations in the #frameImage, that forces the image to those values

Comment: When I do that, images that hit the 150px limit first expand horizontally out or proportion.

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood your question, I thought you wanted to have both 100% and 150px tall, however, you can decide which of the values you want, if you want the width to be always 100% the remove the max prefix from the width atttribute if you would rather have them always be 150px tall remove the max prefix from the height attribute if you remove the max prefix from the height attr be sure to set the width to auto, I would go with the width, it's much more reliable for layout purposes